# OpenSSL support disabled in Apache/PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, laravel, php-openssl

### openssl is disabled apache2.4 with php7.1

in phpinfo(); results give me this

> OpenSSL support   disabled (install ext/openssl)

1. i changed this in php.ini

> extension=php_openssl.dll

2. i use this code using WINDOWS CMD

> set OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/openssl.cnf

3. its enabled when use in CMD this but its disabled in phpinfo();

> php --ri openssl 
>       OpenSSL support => enabled
>       OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
>       Openssl default config => C:/jampp/php71/extras/ssl/openssl.cnf

its now working in CMD and but phpinfo(); not and in laravel 5 show me this error

> Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt()

Thanks

Comment: Are you using wamp?

Comment: no i installed apache 2.4 and php 7.1 manually

Comment: It would help if you cited some references for instructions you followed. Also see [openssl apache php windows enable site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+apache+php+windows+enable+site%3Astackoverflow.com). There are literally pages of results.

Comment: @jww  i opened all the links i googled it too 
but i didn't find the solution

Comment: @MaherBek - Perhaps you should follow some of the instructions rather than opening the link and viewing the page. Some of the answers are quite extensive.

Answer (score 19):

Thank you all its just need includes the (DLLs files of php) into httpd.conf

```
LoadFile "C:/jampp/php/libeay32.dll"
LoadFile "C:/jampp/php/ssleay32.dll"
LoadFile "C:/jampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/jampp/php/libpq.dll"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution for anyone struggling to enable OpenSSL on Windows. Run `php --ini` to check whether your ini file is being ran. In my case the configuration file was set to none.

My php installation came with development and production ini files, but I needed to create a new ini file called php.ini and include my settings there.

If anyone else is struggling to install composer, this fix may work for you :)

Comment: Thanks however it still says PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl'. 
I basically copied php.ini in cli folder to the /usr/local/lib . What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

I have added new php `version 8.2.1` today

1. uncommented `extension_dir = "ext"`
2. uncommented `extension=openssl`
3. Wamp control manager shows that `openssl` is enabled
   [image]

4. Exit wamp and also restarted All services

**Still the Problem persisted on phpinfo() and phpmyadmin**

**The solution** worked for me after all is to **Restart my laptop**

Answer (score 2):

Apply this solution if nothing works like removing semicolon, or extension_dir = ext or absolute path etc, etc...

Open the php folder , find snapshot.txt and open it, in it find

## Module: php_openssl.dll

```
libcrypto-3-x64.dll
libssl-3-x64.dll
```

Now, in this module u are seeing dependency modules which are necessary to be in the apache/bin folder to get enabled. You will find libcrypto-3-x64.dll and libssl-3-x64.dll in php folder itself. Just copy and paste them in apache/bin folder. After that just restart your apache server and openssl support will be enabled.

Well if this solution doesn't work then first check whether you removed semicolon from "**extension=openssl**" , " **extension_dir=ext** " and absolute path " **extension_dir=C:\PHP8\ext**" in the php.ini file or not. If yes then, open cmd terminal and write php --ri openssl , there you will see whether openssl is enabled by php, if it is enabled then you can apply my above solution.

Your Openssl support will definitely be enabled.

Regards, Shane Cox

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer 2021:

OpenSSL is in version 1.1 now. The LoadFiles file in another answer on this page have been replaced by 'libcrypto-1_1.dll' and 'libssl-1_1.dll'.

Honestly, though, that entire answer is probably outdated. In my case, the solution was far simpler. Everything I found on the internet says all you have to do is uncomment the line 'extension=openssl' in your php.ini file. However, there is usually a small piece of information omitted.  You ALSO need to uncomment the line 'extension_dir = "ext"' on Windows or 'extension_dir = "./" on Linux. If you don't do this, then no extensions can load.