# Stomp-php is not visible in xampp *http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php*

Tags: php, xampp, activemq-classic, stomp, php-extension

I just install stomp-php from this site https://pecl.php.net/package/stomp/2.0.2/windows and add copy pasted php_stomp.dll file in 'xampp/php/ext' folder + added 'extension=php_stomp.dll' in PHP in file. Restarted xampp.
but still, I can't see my Stomp extension visible in phpinfo.php.
my Php version is 7.4 and using stomp 2.0.2 of 64 bit.
Is there anything I missed in installation?
can anyone guide me in this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Double check the `extension_dir` setting in your `php.ini` and see if it points to where you placed the DLL. In `phpinfo.php` look for `Configuration File` (or similar) to verify you're editing the correct `php.ini` file. Failing that, look for errors in Apache's log files.

Comment: Yeah Thanks, I got it as I was trying to install the NTS version of stomp which is not suitable for xampp so I tried the TS version and now I can see stomp extension visible in the phpinfo.php file but it's showing me SSL support disabled. What can I do to enable that SSL support? or refer me to any guidance regarding this?
Thanks.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707783/openssl-support-disabled-in-apache-php-on-windows) should help you out.